# AWS CodePipeline - Run at a specific time only if there are changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

AWS: Is it possible to setup a CloudWatch event to run a pipeline at a specific time but only if there are changes on my codecommit repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think is possible out of the box.

An approach could be having a lambda function [executing on a regular schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) (3am). 
Then get your lambda to compare the [latest codepipeline release](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/monitoring-source-revisions-view.html) against your latest revision committed, and trigger the pipeline accordingly.